# Can't add items from listbox to list

Tags: asp.net, list, listbox

I am trying to add all items from a listbox to list(.cs page).I added items to listbox using javascript.Now LstScan.Items.Count return zero always.I can't add items to listbox.Listbox shows values.but problem happens in my .cs file.
here is my code;

Html and javascript Code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function displayKeyCode_demo(e) {
           var code;
           if (!e) var e = window.event;
           if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
           else if (e.which) code = e.which;
           if (code == 13) {
                var textbox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>")
                var listbox = document.getElementById("<%=LstScan.ClientID%>")
                var newOption = document.createElement("Option");
                newOption.value = textbox.value;
                newOption.innerHTML = textbox.value;
                listbox.add(newOption);     
           }
      }
 </script>

 <div>
      <table cellspacing="3px" style="margin: 10px auto 3px 85px;">
           <tr>
                <td width="150px">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="displayKeyCode_demo(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td width="200px">
                     <asp:ListBox ID="LstScan" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="150px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" >
                     </asp:ListBox>
                </td>
           </tr>
      </table>
 </div>
```

here is my code behind code:

```
 List<int> LstSOnum = new List<int>();
 foreach (ListItem item in LstScan.Items) {
      LstSOnum.Add(int.Parse(item.Value));
 }
```

Comment: The browser only posts back the value of the selected option, not the complete option list. you will need to store the option list values in a hidden field(s) that are included with the postback. Note that you probably need to set [`EnableEventValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.80).aspx) to `false` for this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Text

```
 LstSOnum.Add(int.Parse(item.Text));
```

Comment: @ tim sorry.Can you show me how to add entire items to hiddenfields